# How to add image upload fields to active_admin with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, rails-activestorage

I have an Event Model which as many images fields

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :poster
  has_one_attached :ticket_image
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

How can I create and permit images on active admin events dashboard with the above fields?
I am using active_storage as my image uploader

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  ...
  form do |f|
    input :poster, as: :file
    input :ticket_image, as: :file
    input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
  end

  permit_params :poster, :ticket_image, images: []
end
```

Comment: Your answer would be a much better answer if you would add an explanation.